# Swift Generic Constraint cannot convert value

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

In my actual code, the MyFoo object does other things which is an implementation detail that I don't want to share. I'm therefore trying to hide it behind my Foo Protocol, however, I can't find the necessary where clauses to properly map the type:

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype Bar
    func process(bar:Bar)
}

class MyFoo<T>: Foo {
    func process(bar: T) {}
}

class Buzz<U> {
    private let myFoo = MyFoo<U>()

    init<BarProcessor:Foo>(block:(BarProcessor)->Void) where BarProcessor.Bar == U {
        block(myFoo) // error: '(@lvalue MyFoo<U>) -> Void' is not convertible to '(BarProcessor) -> Void'
    }
}
```

Or is there a more fundamental concept I'm missing here as to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't mean what you think it means:

```
init<BarProcessor:Foo>(block:(BarProcessor)->Void) where BarProcessor.Bar == U
```

This is trying to treat `BarProcessor` as a protocol that has been specialized. But it isn't that. `BarProcessor` here is a concrete type. So you're passing a block that accepts some *specific* (but generic) type. You then try to pass `MyFoo` to it, which may not be of that specific type.

When you find yourself mixing protocols and generics this way, you've probably overused protocols. Get rid `Foo`. Protocols are not a way to hide implementation details. The tool to hide implementation details is access control (`private` and `internal`).

If you want to hide types entirely, that's a type eraser, not a protocol. For example (renaming things to what they mean without "Foo" and "Bar"):

```
private struct MyProcessor<T> {
    func process(element: T) {}
}

// Type-erases MyProcessor
struct Processor<T> {
    fileprivate let processor: MyProcessor<T>
    func process(element: T) { processor.process(element: element) }
}

class Machine<U> {
    private let myProcessor = MyProcessor<U>()

    init(block: (Processor<U>)->Void) {
        block(Processor(processor: myProcessor))
    }
}
```

Or, if you have multiple internal implementations of processors that you want to make private, you can use a private protocol, but the key is that the outside world only sees the type-eraser, not the PAT.

```
private protocol Processing {
    associatedtype Element
    func process(element: Element)
}

private struct MyProcessor<T>: Processing {
    func process(element: T) {}
}

struct Processor<T> {
    private let _process: (T) -> ()
    fileprivate init<P: Processing>(_ processor: P) where P.Element == T {
        _process = processor.process
    }
    func process(element: T) { _process(element) }
}

class Machine<U> {
    private let myProcessor = MyProcessor<U>()

    init(block: (Processor<U>)->Void) {
        block(Processor(myProcessor))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, that makes sense. I'm still a little fuzzy on exactly what my code was doing but I get the gist; but using type-erasure achieves the same goal I was trying to anyway.